В чем ошибка кода, я не понимаю, может сработать 1 раз, а потом не работает пол дня
Начал изучать Python и само программирование в целом, по этому я новичек.Писал парсер на Python, но столкнулся с проблемой. Код работает 1 раз, после может не работать, а может и через пол дня снова работать. Вот сам код.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_weather_data(city):
    url = "https://yandex.ru/pogoda"
    response = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")

    # Температура
    block = soup.find("span", class_= "temp__value temp__value_with-unit")
    temperature = block.text.strip()

    # Проявление погоды
    weat = soup.find("div", class_="link__condition day-anchor i-bem")
    weather = weat.text.strip()

    # Ощущение температуры
    temp = soup.find("div", class_= "term term_orient_h fact__feels-like")
    feels_like = temp.text.strip()
    return {
        "Температура": temperature,
        "Погода": weather,
        "Как ощущается": feels_like
    }

print(get_weather_data(city=str))

Выдает вот такую ошибку
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\VS CODE ( MY CODES )\My Codes\parser(site vikipedia)\parserweather.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(get_weather_data(city=str))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\VS CODE ( MY CODES )\My Codes\parser(site vikipedia)\parserweather.py", line 12, in get_weather_data
    temperature = block.text.strip()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^

Прошу, помогите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Яндекс не хочет, чтобы его парсили. Поэтому, периодически, просит подтвердить, что Вы не робот. Тогда парсер и не работает.

Для начала попробуйте дебагнуть и посмотреть что вообще вам возвращает запрос, как сказали выше, вероятнее всего вы после первого запроса получаете блок и вас просят подтвердить что вы не робот, а та как у вас не видно настройки ни юзер агентов, ни прокси, ни других человекоподобных параметров, вероятность блока высока. В вашем случае сначала нужен дебаг и потом (возможно) подключение для решения капчи (в качестве развития).

Спасибо за пояснения! Очень благодарен.
